# Editing order confirmation email in Drupal 7 Commerce

Tags: commerce

I am using Drupal 7 with Drupal Commerce (not Kickstart). I am having difficulties editing the order confirmation email. I am hoping to basically "duplicate" the Order review page from the Checkout process to be included in the email (order items, prices, total and billing info).

The module I installed is [Commerce message](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_message) and I just had no luck trying to edit the order confirmation email. I do have the Tokens module installed and enabled.

I tried to edit the email under Structure -> Message Types, however, the replacement tokens available (for example: `[message:message-commerce-line-item]`), don't seem to output anything in the email. Actually, the token itself is included in the email, like so:

```
<p>[message:message-commerce-line-item]</p>
```

I have tried several other tokens with the same result. I tried to select Filtered HTML and Full HTML.

Reading through the Drupal Answers I also tried to use `!order-summary` token, which seems to work, however the email is "unstyled" and includes HTML tags, like so:

```
<tr class="odd views-row-first views-row-last">
  <td class="views-field views-field-line-item-title" >
     testing credit card payment
  </td>
  <td class="views-field views-field-commerce-unit-price price" >
     $0.25
  </td>
  <td class="views-field views-field-quantity" >
     1
  </td>
  <td class="views-field views-field-commerce-total views-align-right price" >
     $0.25          
  </td>
</tr>
```

What puzzles me the most is seeing answers like [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194461/order-confirmation-email-with-html-content) or [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189196/how-to-add-product-details-to-drupal-commerce-order-confirmation-email), stating that

> You want the Commerce Message module and it's dependencies. It includes customer emails with a full order details, including customer profiles and all the products purchased

Any ideas on the issue? I failed to find any Commerce message tutorial or the way tokens should be used with it in Drupal Commerce. I'd be happy to go through one if it exists, I would be willing to even write one for future users who might have the same problems once I figure this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I the end, I had to install the [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) module. My site uses gmail for the site's email, so I had to use Mime Mail together with [SMTP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module.

The emails render html tags and tokens as needed.

For someone who might experience the similar issue, here is how I configured the Mime Mail witih SMTP:

In `admin/config/system/mailsystem` scroll down to the "New Class" fieldset. Create a new class using `MimeMailSystem` for `format()` and `SmtpMailSystem` for `mail()`. Use that newly created class for the "Site-wide default MailSystemInterface class.

I'm still not completely satisfied with this solution as I was hoping to make Commerce Message to work. If someone ever gets to respond to this I would be thankful for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I though I'd put this out there as what worked for me.

I've had a storefront running on Commerce 7.x-1.x for four years. The order confirmation emails have always been lame, but now with purchasing shifted to web, that lameness was becoming too obvious.

I didn't want to install Commerce Message (for whatever reason), so I started with and edited the standard order confirmation email rule at /admin/commerce/config/checkout/rules.

I added a blend of PHP evalution and replacement patterns from the table beneath the Message text area. Here is the result.  I'll comment it a little (a lot).

```
blah blah blah greetings

Here is a listing of your order:
<?php // start of PHP code insert
    // get the order; it is an entity I think vs. an array (?)
    // that distinction is common throughout this code segment and I'm too php-ignorant to understand it yet
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $commerce_order);  
    // get an array (?) of line items on the order
    $line_items =  $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items->value();
    //loop through each line item
    foreach($line_items as $line_item){ 
        // I want to know if it's 'product' type cuz I treat them differently than 'shipping'.
        // you might see code examples which have this as 
        // $line_item->type->value(), but that just gave me errors.
        $line_item_type = $line_item->type;  
        // again here an ...->amount->value() construction gave me errors
        $unit_price = $line_item->commerce_unit_price['und'][0]['amount']; 
        // here also
        $line_item_total = $line_item->commerce_total['und'][0]['amount']; 
        // if it's product ... 
        if ($line_item_type == 'product') { 
            // casting to (int) gets rid of .00 in quantity.
            // you can't do above if you've got fractional quantities anywhere
            $quantity = (int) $line_item->quantity; 
            // get the product from the line item
            $product = commerce_product_load($line_item->commerce_product['und'][0]['product_id']); 
            // print out qty and product name separated by a few spaces, "x" and tab
            echo $quantity . "  x\t" . $product->title . "\n";  
            // on next line start with tab and spaces, then @, then formatted unit price then line total amount
            echo "\t   @  \$" . number_format($unit_price/100, 2) . " ea ...\t\$" . number_format($line_item_total/100, 2) . "\n";
        } 
        // if it's not 'product' it's 'shipping' and it's always the last one.
        else { 
            // print tab, then "Shipping:  ", then the chosen shipping option, then that unit cost
            echo ucwords($line_item_type) . ":  " . $line_item->data['shipping_service']['display_title'] . " ... \$" . number_format($unit_price/100, 2) . "\n";
        }
    } // end foreach loop
?> // end of PHP code insert

Total incl. tax:  [commerce-order:commerce_order_total] // tax is not available as a distinct element as far as I could tell
Payment:  [commerce-order:payment-method-display-title] // this one is not very descriptive in practice

Your comments:  [commerce-order:field_order_comments]

Shipping address (if applicable):
[commerce-order:commerce_customer_shipping] // this one thankfully spits out all 4-6 lines

blah blah blah nice signoff
```

The end result is an email like so:

```
blah blah blah greeting

Here is a listing of your order: 
1  x    Vivamus at laoreet orci
           @  $25.00 ea ... $25.00 
2  x    Donec eleifend rutrum consequat
           @  $25.00 ea ... $50.00 
2  x    Felis commodo tristique efficitur
           @  $25.00 ea ... $50.00 
Shipping:  Fedex/UPS/Whatever ... $1.23

Total incl. tax:  $132.50 
Payment:  Credit card

Your comments:

Shipping address (if applicable): 
Alfred E Neuman 
123 Elm St 
Anytown, KS  12345 
987-654-3210

blah blah blah nice signoff
```